# How to convert double[] into Double[]?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a data that i need to pass as `Double[]`,
my data is in `double[]`, and i need to pass as `Double[]` because i need
to change it into `List<Double>`

Here is my code

**ListFragment**

```
 @Override
public void OnEditItem(int position) {
    Model selectedItem = mModel.get(position);
    String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();
    String selectedImage = selectedItem.getImagesUri();
    String selecteDescriptions = selectedItem.getImageDescription();
    String selectedImagesName = selectedItem.getImageNames();
    List<Double> selectedataSet = selectedItem.getDataSet();
    double[] zeroSet = new double[selectedataSet.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<zeroSet.length; i++){
        zeroSet[i] = selectedataSet.get(i);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "thisList: " + datacel);
    EditFragment editFragment = new EditFragment();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Label", selectedKey);
    bundle.putString("Image", selectedImage);
    bundle.putString("Descriptions", selecteDescriptions);
    bundle.putString("ImagesName", selectedImagesName);
```

And this is the code that receive the `double[]`

**EditFragment**

```
private void updateView(View view) {
    if(getArguments()!=null){
    String labelId = getArguments().getString("Label");
    String imagesBundle = getArguments().getString("Image");
    String descriptionsBundle =getArguments().getString("Descriptions");
    String imagesNameBundle =getArguments().getString("ImagesName");
    double[] dataSet = getArguments().getDoubleArray("DataSet");

            //this i where i need to change into Double[];

    Log.d(TAG, "thisLIst: " + dataSet);

        etName.setText(String.valueOf(imagesNameBundle));
        etDescribe.setText(descriptionsBundle);
        Picasso.get().load(imagesBundle).into(ImageInput);
        simpleActivity.setDataToListView(value, listViewDataSet,context); // this value need Double[];
```

**Edited**

i think my error starting from here,

```
double[] zeroSet = new 
double[selectedataSet.size()];
for(int i=0; i<zeroSet.length; i++){
    zeroSet[i] = selectedataSet.get(i);
}
```

because the data i got just like this,

[image]

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not complicated at all. You just have to copy the array elements yourself, like

```
double[] dataSet = getArguments().getDoubleArray("DataSet");

Double[] boxedDataSet = new Double[dataSet.length];

for ( int i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++ ) {
  boxedDataSet[i] = dataSet[i]; // Invokes auto-boxing
  // Equivalent, more explicit alternative:
  // boxedDataSet[i] = Double.valueOf(dataSet[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks JimmyB :'D, i think i wanna cry, because your method is working even tough i try to solve this problem for 1 week, really thanks JimmyB

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class BoxArrayExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] arr = new double[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    System.out.println(String.format("Unboxed array: %s", Arrays.toString(arr)));
    Double[] boxedArr = Arrays.stream(arr)
                              .boxed()
                              .toArray(Double[]::new);
    System.out.println(String.format("Boxed array: %s", Arrays.toString(boxedArr)));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Unboxed array: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
Boxed array: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: it doesnt work on android studio, it give me fatal main, and the error, starting from stream to Double[]::new